# URL as environment variable in Node JS

Tags: node.js, rest, url, environment-variables

I was making a micro service for HTTP requests (GET, POST, PUT, DELETE) in Node js and Cassandra. I was wondering if we can set the URL as an environment variable from another file and then pass it to make any specific request?

Comment: yes you can. it would just depend on how your hosting provider handles env variables

Comment: can you elaborate that

Comment: Heroku uses an env file. GCP has you put env variables into your `app.yaml` file. AWS has you put env variables into their dashboard.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a config variable in a config.js file like this:

```
var myConfig = {
   url: <your url>
}

module.exports = myConfig;
```

Then import it in another file:

```
const myConfig = require('./myConfig');

console.log(myConfig.url);
```

Environment variable are handle differently.

You kick off node with environmental variable:

```
URL=<MyURL> node index.js
```

Then you can reference the environmental variable like so:

```
console.log(process.env.URL)
```

Comment: URL=<MyURL> node index.js  what does this line specify exactly?

Comment: This is how you kick off a node script: node index.js. If you put variables in front of it, then you can reference them.

Comment: _Thanks_ a lot.